# sed escaping: single quotes for xpath

Tags: bash, xpath, sed, xml-parsing, escaping

I'm trying to replace single quotes with `sed` when preparing a chunk of XML for xpath parsing with `xmllint`.  According to the xpath spec, I should replace `'` with `&apos;`, and `"` with `&quot;`.  Here are the `sed` expressions I have set up to do that:

`sed "s/'/\&apos;/g" | sed "s/\"/\&quot;/g"`

I know that the `&` character refers to the initial match, so I escaped that, but for some reason these don't seem to work.  The single quote is still not escaped when fed into `xmllint`.  Truncated example:

`XPath error : Invalid predicate
/rss/channel/item[title='...Jeanne d'Arc...']/description
                                    ^
XPath evaluation failure`

The next thing I tried was a double-escape, to no effect.  But interestingly, a triple escape added the replacement expression without removing the initial quote!  I don't understand what is going on here:

`sed "s/'/\\\&apos;/g" | sed "s/\"/\\\&quot;/g"`

`XPath error : Invalid predicate
/rss/channel/item[title='...Jeanne d'apos;Arc...']/description

                                    ^
XPath evaluation failure`

Could somebody explain what is happening here and how to achieve the correct replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
sed "s:':\&apos;:g"|sed 's:":\&quot;:g'
```

1. only need escape **&** character and if you put sed expression into
   double quotes and need replace double quote, you need escape it too,
   otherwise use single quote for this.
2. and same, if you put sed expression into single quotes and need
   replace single quote, you need escape it too, otherwise use double
   quote for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  The problem turned out to be unrelated - I was piping it into a python command to strip urlencoding later on which was undoing my substitutions.  I swapped the order and it works with the original expressions now.